# How do I get feature names when I select only the 20% most important features, using a chi2 test?

Tags: numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

Here is a code snipit I found in the book "Learning scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn import feature_selection
fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=20)
X_train_fs = fs.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

What I want is an array of the feature names and relative importance.

I found this code in Stack ([show feature names after feature selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133348/show-feature-names-after-feature-selection)) but don't totally understand it and have not been able to get it to work.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to get, store and print the features. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried `fs.scores_` attribute? According to the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile) this should give you the features and their scores

Comment: So many attributes; so little time ... thanks Ed! Chris

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code thannks to EdChum

..... read data into numpy arrays

.... get feature names and place into feature_names_

```
from sklearn import feature_selection
fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=20)
X_train_fs = fs.fit_transform(plants_X, plants_y)

print feature_names, '\n', fs.scores_
```