# scikit learn: update countvectorizer after selecting k best features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-processing

I have a count vectorizer with a large number of features, and I would like to be able to select the k best features from a transformed set and then update the count_vectorizer to contain only those features. Is this possible?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as ss
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

merge=re.compile('\*\|.+?\|\*')
def stripmerge(sub):
    for i in merge.findall(sub):
        j=i
        j=j.replace('*|','mcopen')
        j=j.replace('|*','mcclose')
        j=re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]','',j)
        sub=sub.replace(i,j)
    return sub

input=pd.read_csv('subject_tool_test_23.csv')
input.subject[input.subject.isnull()]=' '


subjects=np.asarray([stripmerge(i) for i in input.subject])
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode', ngram_range=(1,1), binary=True, stop_words='english', max_features=500)
counts=count_vectorizer.fit_transform(subjects)

#see the first output example here

from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

good=np.asarray(input.unique_open_performance>0)

count_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=250).fit_transform(counts, good)
```

First output example, features make sense

```
>>> counts[1]
<1x500 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> subjects[1]
"Lake Group Media's Thursday Target"
>>> count_vectorizer.inverse_transform(counts[1])
[array([u'group', u'media', u'thursday'], 
      dtype='<U18')]
```

Second output example, features no longer match up.

```
>>> count_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=250).fit_transform(counts, good)
>>> count_new.shape
(992979, 250)
>>> count_new[1]
<1x250 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> count_vectorizer.inverse_transform(count_new[1])
[array([u'independence', u'easy'], 
      dtype='<U18')]
>>> subjects[1]
"Lake Group Media's Thursday Target"
```

Is there a way to apply the feature selection results to my count vectorizer so that I can generate new vectors with only the important features?

Comment: One potential solution I am trying is to use the information found the post linked below to generate a list of words and then use that as the dictionary for a new count vectorizer. It's not elegant or efficient, but I think it will get the job done.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133348/show-feature-names-after-feature-selection

Comment: What is the motivation for doing this?

Comment: Because the feature list created by using count vectorizer is too large. I would like to select the features that appear be the most relevant and go with those.

Comment: Why don't you use a pipeline of count vectorizer and feature selection?

Comment: I'm relatively new to scikit, and I didn't know about this option. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the case that doing it the way @neelshiv mentions below (creating the new vectorizer with the limited vocab) would obviate the feature selection step for future use (e.g. in a vec+clf pipeline), potentially speeding use on a large dataset?

Answer (score 4):

The way I got around this was by running the feature selection, determining which columns from the original set were selected, creating a dictionary out of those, and then running a new count vectorizer limited to that dictionary. Takes a bit longer with large data sets, but it works.

```
ch2 = SelectKBest(chi2, k = 3000)

count_new = ch2.fit_transform(counts, good)
dict=np.asarray(count_vectorizer.get_feature_names())[ch2.get_support()]
count_vectorizer=CountVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode', ngram_range=(1,1), binary=True,  vocabulary=dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Pipeline to make your life easier. The Pipeline will automatically apply the transformation on the test data. You don't have to manually recreate the vectorizer.

```
text_clf_red = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), 
                       ('reducer', SelectKBest(chi2, k=3000)),
                       ('clf', MultinomialNB())
                       ])

text_clf_red.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_pred = text_clf_red.predict(X_test)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for. It is a modified SelectKBest object that can transform a vocabulary object (term: index dict) or a CountVectorizer object and update its vocabulary. There is no need to re-extract all the features.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
import numpy as np

class CustomSelectKBest(SelectKBest):
  """
    Extending SelectKBest with the ability to update a vocabulary that is given
    from a CountVectorizer object.
  """
  def __init__(self, score_func=f_classif, k=10):
    super(CustomSelectKBest, self).__init__(score_func, k)

  def transform_vocabulary(self, vocabulary):
    mask  = self.get_support(True)
    i_map = { j:i for i, j in enumerate(mask) }
    return { k:i_map[i] for k, i in vocabulary.iteritems() if i in i_map }

  def transform_vectorizer(self, cv):
    cv.vocabulary_ = self.transform_vocabulary(cv.vocabulary_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  def score_func(X, y):
    # Fake scores and p-values
    return (np.arange(X.shape[1]), np.zeros(X.shape[1]))

  # Create test data.
  size = (4, 10)
  X = (np.random.randint(0,5, size=size))
  y = np.random.randint(2, size=size[0])
  vocabulary = {chr(i+ord('a')):i for i in range(size[1])}

  skb = CustomSelectKBest(score_func=score_func, k=5)
  X_s = skb.fit_transform(X, y)
  vocab_s = skb.transform_vocabulary(vocabulary)

  # Confirm they have the right values.
  for k, i_s in vocab_s.iteritems():
    i = vocabulary[k]
    assert((X_s[:,i_s].T == X[:,i].T).all())

  print 'Test passed'
```

Comment: I used this answer so I could save the transformed vocabulary into a json file, for reuse in another run. The accepted answer of np.asarray is "not json-serializable" apparently.