# sklearn: get feature names after L1-based feature selection

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133348/show-feature-names-after-feature-selection) demonstrate that when feature selection is performed using one of scikit-learn's dedicated feature selection routines, then the names of the selected features can be retrieved as follows:

```
np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names())[featureSelector.get_support()]
```

For example, in the above code, `featureSelector` might be an instance of `sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest` or `sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile`, since these classes implement the `get_support` method which returns a boolean mask or integer indices of the selected features.

When one performs [feature selection via linear models penalized with the L1 norm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#l1-based-feature-selection), it's unclear how to accomplish this. `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` has no `get_support` method and the documentation doesn't make clear how to retrieve the feature indices after using its `transform` method to eliminate features from a collection of samples. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For sparse estimators you can generally find the support by checking where the non-zero entries are in the coefficients vector (provided the coefficients vector exists, which is the case for e.g. linear models)

```
support = np.flatnonzero(estimator.coef_)
```

For your `LinearSVC` with l1 penalty it would accordingly be

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
svc = LinearSVC(C=1., penalty='l1', dual=False)
svc.fit(X, y)
selected_feature_names = np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names())[np.flatnonzero(svc.coef_)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to make one edit to your response to get it to work (added a call to numpy.flatnonzero). Once the edit is accepted, I'll mark your answer as accepted (I don't want to confuse anyone in the meantime).

Comment: Thanks for this. Equivalently, you could have used `np.where(svc.coef_ != 0)[0]` instead of `np.flatnonzero`. (Your second edit was rejected, so I made the supplementary corrections you suggest)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using sklearn 15.2, and according to [LinearSVC documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) , coef_ is an array, shape = [n_features] if n_classes == 2 else [n_classes, n_features]. 
So first, `np.flatnonzero` doesn't work for multi-class. You'll have index out of range error. Second, it should be `np.where(svc.coef_ != 0)[1]` instead of `np.where(svc.coef_ != 0)[0]` . 0 is index of classes, not features. I ended up with using `np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names())[list(set(np.where(svc.coef_ != 0)[1]))]`

Comment: True, this gets messy in multiclass. Thanks for the heads-up. The general way of extracting the correct indices should then be `np.where(svc.coef_ != 0)[-1]`, i.e. the last index, which will work for both binary and multiclass problems.