# How to get the selected features after LinearSVC reduction in scikit

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, feature-selection

The title say it all, I have checked [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) docs, which are very poor for this particular task, and I have checked several online resources, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007640/sklearn-get-feature-names-after-l1-based-feature-selection) post.

However, they seem to be wrong. For feature selection we can do something like:

```
clf=LinearSVC(penalty="l1",dual=False,random_state=0)
X_reduced = clf.fit_transform(X_full,y_full)
```

Now, if we inspect the shape of `X_reduced`, it is very clear how many features were selected. So the question is now, which ones?

The `coef_` attribute of the `LinearSVC` is very important and is suggested to iterate over it and the features which `coef_` are different from zero are the ones selected. Well, **this is wrong**, but you can get very close to the real result.

After checking `X_reduced`, I noticed I got 310 selected features, and that is for sure, I mean, I am checking the resultant matrix, now, if I do the `coef_` thing, 414 features were selected, from a total of 2000, so it is close to the real thing.

According to scikit [`LinearSVC` docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) there is a `mean(X)` involved for `Threshold=None` but I am stuck, no idea what to do now.

**UPDATE**: Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6zqf2dip41pxo6/errorScikit.rar?dl=0) with data&code that reproduce the error, its just a few KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `LinearSVC()` does returns features with non-zero coefficients. Could you please upload the sample data file and code script (for example, via dropbox sharelink) that can reproduce the inconsistency you saw?

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import numpy as np

X, y = load_svmlight_file("/home/Jian/Downloads/errorScikit/weirdData")

transformer = LinearSVC(penalty='l1', dual=False, random_state=0)
transformer.fit(X, y)
# set threshold eps
X_reduced = transformer.transform(X, threshold=np.finfo(np.float).eps)

print(str(X_reduced.shape[1]) + " is NOW equal to " + str((transformer.coef_ != 0).sum()))

414 is NOW equal to 414


# as suggested by user3914041, if you want both sides are 310
transformer.transform(X).shape

Out[46]: (62, 310)

(abs(transformer.coef_) > 1e-5).sum()

Out[47]: 310
```

Comment: Thanks, here it is: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6zqf2dip41pxo6/errorScikit.rar?dl=0)

Comment: @nxgtrturbo I saw the same inconsistency as you did. If I set the threshold to be a very small value (for example, `eps` here), it give the expected result.

Comment: Yeah, however the objective is to reach to the 310 on both sides, as this is part of a custom pipeline that gets several different reduction methods (not all of them using Threshold). Would you say it is a bug? or at least wrong documentation?

Comment: @nxgtrturbo I agree that [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) are not the most precise. They do mention that you can set a threshold but I have not seen the default value written anywhere. However looking at the source code you can see that for a L1 penalty the threshold defaults to 1e-5.

Comment: @nxgtrturbo As @user3914041 suggests, the source code `transformer.transform??` shows that `1e-5` is used as default threshold. I've modified the code to get you 310.