# How to get the selected features with their scores?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

With reference to [Map object is not subscriptable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133348/show-feature-names-after-feature-selection)
I used Moses Xu answer to get the feature names. It produces the error "Map object is not subscriptable". The code is below. I am using python 3.x

```
top_ranked_features = sorted(enumerate(ch2.scores_),key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:1000]
top_ranked_features_indices = map(list,zip(*top_ranked_features))[0]
for feature_pvalue in zip(np.asarray(train_vectorizer.get_feature_names())[top_ranked_features_indices],ch2.pvalues_[top_ranked_features_indices]):
    print( feature_pvalue).
```

The error is in the second line of code.

OUTPUT

```
('00 8b 4d fc', 3.4028916591534005e-61)
('51 00 22 05', 3.4028916591534005e-61)
('00 74 00 61', 8.3973527363656966e-61)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.x, map returns an iterator, rather than a list. Thus, the returned object is not subscriptable.
You could change it to `list(map(list,zip(*a)))[0]` to solve the problem.

Edited:

You could also use `next(map(list,zip(*a)))` to not load the scores to memory, and keep the code more pythonic.

Comment: @banu adding an extra question to the same post only creates mess. It appears as if you get an error and a proper output. Please remove the second question. You could either ask a new question in a new post, or search for an existing solution.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for guidance.